# Catel (mvvm) and WCF

Tags: wpf, wcf, catel

Is anyone successfully using Catel's `Catel.Data.SavableModelBase` and WCF?  As soon as I inherit from this class, my attributes all come across `null` when retrieving the `SavableModelBase<T>` object through WCF.

Do I need to do anything special?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work out of the box. Please make sure that you are using the latest version. If you case doesn't work, please create an issue here:

http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/